# Develop a plugin for squash TM

Tags: java, plugins, squash

I want to develop a specific plugin for Squash TM and I don't know where to start

I have read many topics on the Squash TM `https://sites.google.com/a/henix.fr/wiki-squash-tm/` but nothing helped me 
There is no developper's guide on the official site of Squash TM
So, I asked here if someone have already developped a plugin for Squash TM
What are the requirements

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to contribute to Squash TM project, don't hesitate to contact the Henix team by sending a mail on this address: contact@squashtest.org

If you want to develop this plugin internally, you can have an access to source code and all needed documentation on this website: www.squashtest.org

I hope it will answer your question.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer 
I have already downloaded the source code but it has no update since january 2018

Answer (score 0):

For those who want develop plugin for Squash TM, Squash has a maven repository which contains all dependencies you need for developping a plugin or anything else 
this is the link: [Squash repository](http://repo.squashtest.org/maven2/releases/)